# Is it grammatically correct "Retry the failing activity, as the clock has past the remaining time"?

Tags: grammar

Someone suggested that the phrase "Retry the failing activity, as the clock has past the remaining time" is not grammatically correct because it is missing a verb after "has".

I understand that "past" isn't a verb but I think "has" can act as a verb. I would like to know if we really need a verb after "has" or the above statement is correct?

Comment: *have* can be a verb meaning *possess*, which would not make sense here. I think the intended phrase is "the clock has passed the remaining time", which would still be an unfortunate construction, though it would be closer to being sensible. If you explain what the real meaning intended by the phrase is, someone can probably help you with a clear and idiomatic phrasing.

Comment: Your interpretation of the phrase is correct. The intent of the phrase is to send a message that we need to retry the failing activity because the clock has moved forward and passed the remaining time.

You are using pass as a verb here. My question is that can we instead use "has" as a verb here?

Comment: No, you would not use "have" as a non-auxiliary verb this way here. It sounds like the writer might mean "Time's up. Try again." or "You have run out of time. Please try again." or "Activity failed because the allowed time was exceeded. Retry."